# print! macro not executed until pressing Enter

Tags: rust

I am studying Rust and upon working on the [Guessing Game](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html) I found this odd behaviour:

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Welcome!");

    let mut input = String::new();
    print!("Please type something:"); // this line is not printed UNTIL the Enter key is pressed
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Failed to read input!");

    println!("Bye!");
}
```

The following happens:

1. `Welcome!` is printed
2. `Please type something:` is NOT printed
3. If you type some text and press Enter, you will see your text followed by `Please type something:Bye!`

How can I print a message to the standard output and have the input being printed on the same line?

For instance:

```
Please enter your name:
(user types Chuck Norris)
Please enter your name: Chuck Norris
```

Comment: Could be related to [not flushing the output buffer](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23818)?

Comment: @tadman Indeed I can `print!("Something\n") but then the \n is printed.

Comment: See the associated issue I linked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the docs for [`std::print`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.print.html):

> Note that stdout is frequently line-buffered by default so it may be necessary to use io::stdout().flush() to ensure the output is emitted immediately.

So looks like you need to import `std::io::Write` and call [`io::stdout().flush()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.flush).

Comment: Thank you that works! I will accept your answer as soon as the 10 min delay has passed.